# Node oracle returns "UnKnown Error " with select statements

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am trying to use Node-Oracle package for an application but the select statement returns with "UnKnown Error".

I am able to create a table with the connection object without error but only fails with select statement. I have seen similar issue filed in node -oracle forum and there was no answer for the issue created. I am using oracle express server locally on windows 8 machine .

I have spent a lot of time trying to play around roles of the oracle account/schema I am using but has not helped. I also was able to connect using a sample dot net application without error and execute select statement .

Any suggestion on how to at least figure the actual error would be very helpful .

Thanks in advance.

Edit : I was able to confirm that the error is in the node oracle module , but I am not sure why I see this . All my effort to contain the error in a try catch block in the c++ connection.cpp file is 
not working . I am stuck now . Not sure if if it has to do with windows 8 machine .